# FB_FileGets vs FB_FileRead in twincat

Tags: twincat

There are two similar function for reading file in `twincat` software for [Beckhoff](https://www.beckhoff.com/) company. [FB_FileGets](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibsystem/html/tcplclibsys_fb_fileread.htm&id=) and [FB_FileRead](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibsystem/html/tcplclibsys_fb_fileread.htm&id=). I will be appreciate if someone explain what are the differences of these function and clear when we use each of them. both of them have same ‌prerequisite or not, use in same way in programs? which one has better speed(fast reading in different file format) and any inform that make them clear for better programming.

[image]vs[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `FB_FileGets` reads the file line by line. So when you call it, you always get a one line of the text file as string. The maximum length of a line is 255 characters. So by using this function block, it's very easy to read all lines of a file. No need for buffers and memory copying, if the 255 line length limit is ok.

THe `FB_FileRead`reads given number of bytes from the file. So you can read files with for example 65000 characters in a single line.

I would use the `FB_FileGets` in all cases where you know that the lines are less than 255 characters and the you handle the data as line-by-line. It's very simple to use. If you have no idea of the line sizes, you need all data at once or the file is very big, I would use the `FB_FileRead`.

I haven't tested but I think that the `FB_FileRead`is probably faster, as it just copies the bytes to buffer. And you can read the whole file at once, not line-by-line.